# Switching from have been to current tense in a sentence

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

While working on a project with a friend, we stumbled upon a grammatical problem.

> These use cases have been modeled and help convey the game’s primary gameplay.

I'm uncertain whether or not it's acceptable to switch between past tense "have been" to current tense "help."

I'm wondering if the following, would be better suited:

> These use-cases have been modeled and have helped convey the game’s primary gameplay.

My friend argues that the alternative I proposed doesn't clarify that *the use-cases still convey the game's primary gameplay* to this date.

Are both correct, or is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Why do you think that *have* and *help* are in different tenses? They are not: both are present tense. To be in different tenses you would have to pair **either** present-tense *have* with past-tense *helped* **or else** past-tense *had* with present-tense *help*.

Answer (score -1):

The simple present tense can be used to convey a general truth. In the context of your sentence, "help convey the game's primary gameplay," is a general truth. It is true today; it was true in the past; and it will be true in the future. "These use cases have been modeled," is the foundation of the general truth.

https://www.englishgrammar.org/simple-present-tense/

Comment: Nonsense. It’s a statement of a past event. The sentence doesn’t actually state whether the model is doing the helping, and the default assumption is that these are two separate statements of fact which have nothing to do with universal truths.